# Custom layer in Keras: def call

Tags: python, keras, layer

How does to implement custom layer in Keras? What does argument 'x' in def call mean?

I need to implement layer with (num,4,4) weights that takes (num,4,4) array as input and multiply each slice (every of num (4,4) input arrays) by corresponding slice of weights. So I want to have (num,1,1) outputs.

I try to do this:

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    num = self.input_len
    res=np.zeros((num,1,1))
    for i in range(num):
        print(x[i,:,:])
        res[i,0,0]=K.dot(x[i,:,:], self.W[i,:,:])
    return res
```

but I have the error:

```
    /home/universal/anaconda3/envs/practicecourse2/mylayer.py in call(self, x, mask)
     26         for i in range(num):
     27             print(x[i,:,:])
---> 28             res[i,0,0]=K.dot(x[i,:,:], self.W[i,:,:])
     29         return res
     30 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I should use

```
res= K.sum(x*self.W,axis=(2,3))
```

instead of

```
for i in range(num):
    print(x[i,:,:])
    res[i,0,0]=K.dot(x[i,:,:], self.W[i,:,:])
```